# groff: How can I correctly render paragraphs between embedded images?

Tags: pdf, text-formatting, groff

I have the following [groff](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/groff.1.html) source using the [mom](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/groff_mom.7.html) macros:

```
.PRINTSTYLE TYPESET
.CAPTION_AFTER_LABEL IMG
.START
.PDF_IMAGE img/uc1.pdf 657p 152p SCALE 70 CAPTION "Figure 1: Activity diagram for UC1"
.PP
Placeholder text 1
.PDF_IMAGE img/uc2.pdf 345p 61p CAPTION "Figure 2: Activity diagram for UC2"
.PP
Placeholder text 2
.PDF_IMAGE img/uc3.pdf 517p 301p SCALE 75 CAPTION "Figure 3: Activity diagram for UC3"
.PP
Placeholder text 3
.PDF_IMAGE img/uc4.pdf 540p 470p SCALE 75 CAPTION "Figure 4: Activity diagram for UC4"
.PP
Placeholder text 4
```

It renders like this:

[image: example incorrect render]

Since the third image cannot fit on the first page, the third image is pushed onto the next page, which is fine. However, the problem is `Placeholder text 3` and `Placeholder text 4` should appear after the third image and fourth images respectively on the next page, rather than immediately after the second image on the first page. I.e., I want the paragraphs to appear after the preceding image in the generated PDF, in the same order as in the groff source.

None of the arguments to the [`PDF_IMAGE` macro](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/images.html#pdf-image) look like they would fix this problem.

I tried using the [`ALD` macro](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/typesetting.html#ald) to move the vertical position on the page, thinking that the `PDF_IMAGE` macro was throwing off the vertical position, but that just caused a large vertical gap of whitespace before the paragraphs.

How can I fix this?

**How I compile the PDF**

```bsh
pdfmom example.mom > example.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

troff has the concept of a *floating keep*. In `mom` this is provided by the `.FLOAT` macro. Content between the start and end of the float is kept on the same page, but may slide over other output to achieve this. The option `FORCE` avoids this.  The [macro](https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/images.html#floats-intro)  resets the text justification to *no fill*, so you would need to use `.JUSTIFY` within the float to undo this, but you already have a `.PP` which should include this. Example:

```
.FLOAT FORCE
.PDF_IMAGE img/uc1.pdf 657p 152p SCALE 70 CAPTION "Figure 1: Activity diagram for UC1"
.PP
Placeholder text 1
.FLOAT OFF
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I get an `environment stack overflow` error. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Apart from the error message, does it seem to work?

Comment: No, it doesn't fix the problem. The resulting PDF looks the same.

Comment: Did you put a `.FLOAT FORCE` `.FLOAT OFF` around each image and the placeholder text that follows? I don't have your pdf images and so on, but I tried with some pdf's on my old groff version 1.22.3 and it seemed to work, moving the text on to below the image. I also got the error messages though. What version are you using?

Comment: Ah, the problem was I didn't put `.FLOAT FORCE` `.FLOAT OFF` around *every* image and placeholder text, only around the first two. It is working now (with the same `environment stack overflow` message as before) when I put it around every image and placeholder text. Thanks!

Comment: That said, it would be nice if there was a solution that didn't emit any warnings or errors.

Comment: I agree. It feels like a bug. The documentation says that since some version each image is now automatically in a float. So we have a float in an implied float, which may not have been well tested. But the doc does suggest that it should work.